# Best practices whilst trying to adopt C++ templates and code reuse

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am working on a wxWidgets project in which the new menu item populates a series of input boxes with a predefined value. There are over 40 different starter templates for this particular feature.

Is there a way that I can add this feature without having to write 40+ different menu_clicked event functions? In which the only difference is the text to be populated into the UI.

Example:

```
File -> New -> Option 1 //On_Click() {update textboxes with option 1 values}
               Option 2 //On_Click() {update textboxes with option 2 values}
               Option 3 //On_Click() {update textboxes with option 3 values}
               ...
               Option 40 //On_Click() {update textboxes with option 40 values}
```

What would be the most efficient way of doing this through C++ templating? Is this kind of feature possible / easier than writing out each function manually?

Comment: Sounds like you need `std::unordered_map` to map from option ID into a collection of textboxes. Then each option would be an instance of a single class, that implements a function to update the designated text boxes. If this class would have a field with option ID, then it could retrive the designated text boxes

Comment: @hdcdigi, take a look at the docview sample. It kind of implements what you are looking for with its "File -. New" menu...

Comment: @hdcdigi, or you can have a toolbar/ aui toolbar, with dedicated tools for such options and don't use menu at all.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need templates for this. Just create a single handler function, connect it to the whole range of IDs (`Bind()` allows to specify the first and last ID and not just a single one) and then use `event.GetId() - ID_FIRST` to get the index of the option you're dealing with (fixing off-by-one errors is left as exercise to the reader).

Comment: Ok cool I will look into this, I am guessing I will need some kind of switch statement inside the handler to process each request.

Comment: No, the point is that you don't need any `switch`, as you can just get the ID of the chosen option directly from the `wxCommandEvent` object your handler receives.